# What are the difference between various iOS versions with a developer prespective?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

This questions bounces around with every other new release of iOS. So I decided to jot down all the differences I know from version to version. Let me know if they are more.

Comment: The first 2 lines should be the question, the rest is the answer itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**iOS 4.0**

1. Multitasking (Introduction of GCD and Blocks)
2. Local Notifications
3. iAds
4. Event Kit (For Calender access)
5. High resolution screen support

**iOS 4.1**

1. Game center and leaderboards

**iOS 4.2**

1. AirPlay
2. Wireless Printing

**iOS 4.3**

1.AirPlay Video Support

**iOS 5.0**

1. iCloud
2. Automated Reference Counting
3. Storyboards
4. NewsStand Support
5. Twitter Framework

**iOS 5.1**

1. Dictation Support for Text view.

**iOS 6.0**

1. Maps
2. Social Framework (Facebook & Twitter)
3. Passkit
4. GameCenter
5. Remainders
6. In App Purchase
7. Auto layout
8. Collection Views

There is an Apple documentation available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS)

Comment: ARC was not added in iOS 5. ARC is a feature of newer compilers. ARC can be used in iOS apps that support iOS 4.3.

Comment: In App Purchase was not added into iOS 6.0. It was added in iOS 3.0.

Comment: Why are maps and game center listed under iOS 6.0?

Comment: please update answer and also update it by adding iOS7

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget deprecation of viewDidUnload and other UIViewController methods ;)

Also deprecation of some retain properties

Comment: I believe the point of this "question" is to point out differences in iOS features, not API differences.

Comment: I'd say they are enhancements! Anything that improves memory management, or deallocation of unused assets is definitely an improvement.

Comment: I'm not referring to the merit of the deprecation. I'm referring to the point of this "question". It seems that the point is to list iOS features. There is no point in listing API differences since that is already documented on Apple's website and the reference documentation.

Comment: i guess it all boils down to what someone would consider a feature, an enhancement, Bug Fixes, or modification. I suppose we can all collectively agree that most of these idiosyncrasies strive to make the OS better. If you read above there is a portmanteau of both IOS Features and API stuff in the list by Sumit. Framework would imply SDK/API. Seems like some entail both, it's hard to differentiate IOS Feature vs API difference since the overlap.